# Powershell - creating scheduled task

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to create powershell script, which should set scheduled task. This is my code:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell' -Argument 'C:\script.ps1'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 11am 
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskPath "custom_tasks" -TaskName "customtask"
```

This script is by SCCM runned on computers. Problem is in assigned user, under this task should run. In task scheduler there is mentioned user `computername$` for this task, and there is condition - this user has to be logged in. However this user will never be logged in, because people use another - their personal account. So task will never run.

Is possible to specify in script, that account has not to be logged in? I didn't found any solution for my problem.

Summary:
Task which is set by script will never run, because in created task is wrong account (which is not using). There is also condition which is saying: task will be activated only when this account is logged in. So this task will never run.

Comment: I don't know if I got your question right. but you can set a trigger which will be activated everytime when someone logs in. `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon`. Check the documentation for triggers: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-5-register-a-scheduled-task-that-starts-when-a-user-logs-on)

Comment: @guiwhatsthat it will be activated when any one logs in or it will be activated only with some specific user?

Comment: Who runs the PS script to create the Scheduled Task?  Doesn't user have to be logged-in to create the scheduled task?

Comment: Both is possible read the documentation which I linked

Comment: @rumcajs are you wanting it to run in the context of like a system account?  And you want the setting "Run whether user is logged in or not" enabled?